# How to change only the last part of the URL with a data router in React Router DOM?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a subrouter and need to change only the last part of the URL, e.g. `/some/long/path/with/ids` -> `/some/long/path/with/ids/next` and back `/some/long/path/with/ids/next` -> `/some/long/path/with/ids`.

Until I switched to a data router `` navigate(`../${step[index].path}`) `` worked fine, but now it is broken

Full example:

```
import {
  RouterProvider,
  createBrowserRouter,
  useRoutes,
  useNavigate,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />
  },
  {
    path: "/some/:long/path/:with/ids/*",
    element: <Wizard />
  }
]);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      home <Link to="/some/long/path/with/ids">go to wizard</Link>
    </>
  );
}

const steps = [
  {
    path: "",
    element: <Step1 />
  },
  {
    path: "next",
    element: <Step2 />
  }
];

function Wizard() {
  const routes = useRoutes(steps);

  return <>{routes}</>;
}

function Step1() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <>
      step 1
      <button onClick={() => navigate(steps[1].path)}>go to step 2</button>
    </>
  );
}

function Step2() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <>
      step 2
      <button onClick={() => navigate(steps[0].path)}>go back to step 1</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-feynman-q3l8ml?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

As you can see going to step 2 works fine, but going back is not working as intended. I could change it to `` navigate(`../${steps[index].path}`) ``, but then it doesn't work for step 2.

Comment: ```navigate(`../${steps[index].path}`)``` works for me in your sandbox, I can navigate back to the first step. Are you looking for a general-purpose/universal target path that will work for any wizard step?

Comment: @DrewReese yes, ```navigate(`../${steps[index].path}`)``` doesn't work when you go to the second step

Comment: It is working for me, in your sandbox. I can click the buttons on step 1 and 2 and get navigated between the two steps. https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-change-only-the-last-part-of-the-url-with-a-data-router-in-react-router-d-nr34w7 Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @DrewReese you didn't change `navigate(steps[1].path)` to ```navigate(`../${steps[1].path}`)```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify that only one target path is the issue, the one navigating back to step 1. There's no issue with using `<button onClick={() => navigate(steps[1].path)}>go to step 2</button>` to navigate to "step 2". `navigate("next")` is correct for a relative navigation from `"/some/long/path/with/ids"` to `"/some/long/path/with/ids/next"`. Step 2 basically needs `navigate("..")` to get back to `"/some/long/path/with/ids"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the last of the URL using `navigate(-1)`

```
<button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>go back to step 1</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't it just go back in history? If there are more steps it won't work. Or if someone clicks a link with step 2